# The form does not "get out"

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are two buttons, the first opens a form in which there are many inputs (it works), and the second button it should also open the form (does not work)

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
const closeButton = document.querySelector('#closeButton');
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const del = document.querySelector(".del")

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  openForm();
}); //вызов функции открытия формы

closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  closeForm();
}); //вызов функции закрытия формы

const openForm = () => {
  form.classList.add('open');
  popup.classList.add('popup_open');
}; //функция открытия формы

const closeForm = () => {
  form.classList.remove('open');
  popup.classList.remove('popup_open');
}
```

```css
.form {
  display: none;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

.del {
  display: none;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}

.open1 {
  display: block;
}

#id,
#N_m,
#name,
#Adr,
#Full_name,
#Phone {
  width: 305px;
}

#closeButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

#wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

#wrapper1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.string {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.65fr 0.65fr;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: none;
}

.popup1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: none;
}

.popup_open {
  display: block;
}

.popup_open1 {
  display: block;
}

.popup__container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 588px;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup__container1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 588px;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup__wrapper {
  padding: 40px;
}

.popup__wrapper1 {
  padding: 40px;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.del1 {
  color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="new.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="popup__container">
      <div class="popup__wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <form method="POST" class="form">
            <button class="exit" class="exit" id="closeButton">х</button>
            <div class="string">
              <label for="id">Надпись:</label>
              <input type="number" id="id" name="id_k1" required>
            </div>
            <div class="string">
              <label for="N_m">Надпись:</label>
              <input type="text" id="N_m" name="n_mine" required>
            </div>
            <div class="string">
              <label for="name">Надпись:</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name_mine" required>
            </div>
            <div class="string">
              <label for="Adr">Надпись:</label>
              <input type="text" id="Adr" name="adress" required>
            </div>
            <div class="string">
              <label for="Full_name">Надпись:</label>
              <input type="text" id="Full_name" name="full_name_of_direcor" required>
            </div>
            <div class="string">
              <label for="Phone">Надпись:</label>
              <input type="tel" id="Phone" name="phone_number" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="contact">Отправить в БД</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="button" type="submit" name="submit" class="button">Открыть форму</button>

  <div class="popup1">
    <div class="popup__container1">
      <div class="popup__wrapper1">
        <div id="wrapper1">
          <form method="POST" class="del">
            <button class="exit" class="exit" id="closeButton">х</button>
            <p>Введите или выберете номер записи, которую хотите удалить</p>
            <div class="string">
              <label for="id">Надпись:</label>
              <input type="number" id="id" name="id_k1" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="contact">Удалить запись</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="del" type="submit" name="submit" class="del1">Удалить запись</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to remove add styles, as you understand, it did not lead to anything.I repeat, I want the buttons to different forms.

Comment: IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look and it looks like you are selecting the first button with `document.querySelector('#button')`, which selects the first button on the page. You are later adding an event listener to that using this code:

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  openForm();
})
```

That works.

For the second button, you have given it an ID of `del` and a class name of `del1`. You seem to be trying to select it by the ID, but you are using the class selector with `const del = document.querySelector(".del")`. That should either be updated to:

```
const del = document.querySelector(".del1") // selects using the class name
```

or

```
const del = document.querySelector("#del") // selects using the ID
```

Now that you have selected your button, you need to add the event listener to that. It looks like you added it for the first button but not the second. It should be something like this:

```
del.addEventListener('click', () => {
  openForm();
})
```

I hope that helps.